# why sp_analytics_dashboard doesn't show in wso2 api manager console service providers when I enable analytics?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I just enabled wso2 analytics settings in wso2 API manager deployment.conf file, but I can't find sp_analytics_dashboard setting in service providers of carbon console.what is the problem?

Comment: What is your APIM version?

Comment: @Lakshitha
3.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the quick setup[1] and not the standard setup[2], you need to place the unzipped API-M pack and unzipped Analytics pack inside the same directory. This is because the default configurations such as database connection URLs etc are configured assuming that both the packs are inside the same folder.

[image]

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#quick-setup.
[2] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/analytics/configuring-apim-analytics/#standard-setup